# String concatenate not working because of null

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am attempting to add the previous value of a column to another string but I fear because it is null.

```
async def set_info_id(message_id, server_id):
    message_id = str(message_id) + '.'
    async with aiosqlite.connect('database/tickets.db') as db:
        sql = f'UPDATE servers SET info_message_id = info_message_id || {message_id} WHERE serverid = {server_id}'
        await db.execute(sql,)
        await db.commit()
```

That is the code I am using. Is there any way for concatenate to work when it is null to begin with?

Comment: you probably also want to be using parameterised queries (i.e. pass `message_id` and `server_id` to `execute`) to protect against sql injection attacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE servers
    SET info_message_id = COALESCE(info_message_id, '') || {message_id}
    WHERE serverid = {server_id};
```

You might want to reconsider your data model, though.  A separate table a separate row for with each message/server combination seems like a better approach -- particularly if the ids are numbers.

Comment: Too fast for me. :)

Comment: Yeah, I see that now haha. Thank you for the help and suggestion I'll work on rewriting this soon.